# angular checkbox update is not updating the model

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, checkbox

I'm trying to change a checkbox value based on another checkbox value, but the change doesn't seem to have any effect in the model.

Here is a code example of the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eFOn3cejwKU01LkKNC1s?p=preview

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

      <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
        <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
      <pre>
      A value: {{a}}
      B value: {{b}}
      </pre>
          A <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a" />
          B <input type="checkbox" ng-model="b" 
            ng-disabled="a"
            ng-checked="!a && b"
          />

      </body>

    </html>
```

And an empty controller:

```
var app = angular.module('main', [])
        .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {

        });
```

As far as I've read, a Dom change doesn't change the model, and when I try to call $apply, the digest is already running, so I'm a bit lost.

I don't want to put a $watch on the first checkbox because my example is already quite complex.

Is there any alternative solution that does not involve writing js code in the controller for this problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to change one checkbox based on clicking of another? From what I interpret, it looks like you are trying to check one if the other isn't checked? Could you elaborate just to be clear. You shouldn't need a watch for this.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to set the b model to false when a is checked. So the full demonstration would be check b, then check a, b is disabled and unchecked and the b model is still true

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, my real problem is quite more complex than this one, this is just a simplification to ilustrate it. My final solution is going to be to $watch the "a" element, that's because even when the b got unchecked, as soon as have been a dom modification and even when it have been triggered by an angular directive, it's not going to be processed in the digest, so if there is no event on the dom element or model change, the digest will not take into consideration that change.

Comment: I would recommend trying to illustrate that much more clearly if you are looking for help. Your question above seems like it is asking about simply changing the check boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/lbOWO4oLbTghactUETTD?p=preview

You missed reference to script

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.3/ng-table.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ops, seems that I didn't saved the plunkr, is my first one, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plunker showing a way to set the b value in the model to false when a is clicked and set to true, without modifying the controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rL6tTp5NfBzroZ2zSOgO?p=preview

And here is what I modified to do it - see the ng-change

```
A <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a" ng-change="b=!a" />
```